# Finding FIT for real temperature and shifting time data and Black body error subtraction

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, fitting, physics

First cooling section:

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\ja\\Desktop\\new cooling data.xlsx"]; 
data2 = Flatten[data]; 
data3 = Partition[data2, 2]; 
time = data3[[All,1]]; 
temperature = data3[[All,2]]; 
Length[data3]
(*35908*)

coolingpart1 = data3[[6010 ;; 12029 ;; 50]]

(*
{{10.01512, 46.761}, {10.09847, 46.326}, {10.1818, 45.272}, {10.26512, 44.027}, {10.34847, 42.91}, {10.4318, 42.012}, {10.51512, 41.071}, {10.59845, 40.323}, {10.6818, 39.626}, {10.76513, 38.947}, 
  {10.84845, 38.268}, {10.93182, 37.874}, {11.01515, 37.217}, {11.09847, 36.823}, {11.1818, 36.429}, {11.26515, 35.947}, {11.34848, 35.487}, {11.4318, 35.071}, {11.51515, 34.808}, {11.59848, 34.48}, 
  {11.6818, 34.261}, {11.76513, 33.975}, {11.84848, 33.661}, {11.93182, 33.306}, {12.01513, 33.078}, {12.09848, 32.923}, {12.18182, 32.598}, {12.26513, 32.397}, {12.34847, 32.222}, {12.43182, 32.09}, 
  {12.51515, 31.875}, {12.59847, 31.653}, {12.68182, 31.521}, {12.76515, 31.346}, {12.84847, 31.171}, {12.9318, 31.083}, {13.01515, 30.842}, {13.09848, 30.842}, {13.1818, 30.649}, {13.26515, 30.47}, 
  {13.34848, 30.452}, {13.4318, 30.251}, {13.51513, 30.12}, {13.5985, 30.098}, {13.68183, 29.854}, {13.76515, 29.517}, {13.8485, 29.404}, {13.93183, 29.382}, {14.01515, 29.382}, {14.09848, 29.382}, 
  {14.18183, 29.337}, {14.26517, 29.27}, {14.34848, 29.094}, {14.43183, 29.049}, {14.51517, 29.023}, {14.59848, 28.935}, {14.68182, 28.759}, {14.76517, 28.694}, {14.8485, 28.694}, {14.93182, 28.672}, 
  {15.01517, 28.566}, {15.0985, 28.431}, {15.18182, 28.365}, {15.26515, 28.322}, {15.3485, 28.326}, {15.43183, 28.256}, {15.51518, 28.19}, {15.59853, 28.037}, {15.68187, 27.997}, {15.76518, 27.993}, 
  {15.84852, 27.971}, {15.93187, 27.971}, {16.0152, 27.928}, {16.09852, 27.796}, {16.18187, 27.73}, {16.2652, 27.665}, {16.34852, 27.647}, {16.43185, 27.625}, {16.5152, 27.621}, {16.59853, 27.581}, 
  {16.68185, 27.533}, {16.7652, 27.446}, {16.84853, 27.358}, {16.93185, 27.292}, {17.01518, 27.296}, {17.09853, 27.296}, {17.18185, 27.274}, {17.26518, 27.274}, {17.34853, 27.187}, {17.43187, 27.139}, 
  {17.51518, 27.052}, {17.59852, 26.985}, {17.68187, 26.963}, {17.76518, 26.941}, {17.84852, 26.918}, {17.93187, 26.918}, {18.0152, 26.873}, {18.09853, 26.81}, {18.18187, 26.788}, {18.26522, 26.694}, 
  {18.34853, 26.631}, {18.43187, 26.581}, {18.51522, 26.581}, {18.59855, 26.559}, {18.68187, 26.559}, {18.7652, 26.559}, {18.84855, 26.559}, {18.93187, 26.559}, {19.0152, 26.537}, {19.09855, 26.469}, 
  {19.18188, 26.424}, {19.2652, 26.335}, {19.34853, 26.271}, {19.43188, 26.245}, {19.5152, 26.245}, {19.59853, 26.223}, {19.68188, 26.227}, {19.76522, 26.223}, {19.84853, 26.2}, {19.93187, 26.2}, 
  {20.01522, 26.2}}
*)

PR1 = NonlinearModelFit[coolingpart1, a*Exp[-t/taus] + c, {a, c, taus}, t]

PR1["ParameterTable"]

PR1[1.9]
(*1368.6152307779912*)
```

Second cooling section:

```
coolingpart2 = data3[[18050 ;; 24000 ;; 50]]

(*
{{30.08228, 46.702}, {30.16563, 45.939}, {30.24897, 44.6}, {30.33228, 43.508}, {30.41562, 42.432}, {30.49897, 41.425}, {30.5823, 40.64}, {30.66562, 39.808}, {30.74897, 39.126}, {30.8323, 38.516}, 
  {30.91562, 37.903}, {30.99895, 37.374}, {31.0823, 36.852}, {31.16563, 36.479}, {31.24895, 36.041}, {31.3323, 35.564}, {31.41563, 35.107}, {31.49895, 34.863}, {31.58228, 34.531}, {31.66563, 34.25}, 
  {31.74897, 33.986}, {31.83228, 33.672}, {31.91563, 33.336}, {31.99897, 33.137}, {32.08228, 32.936}, {32.16562, 32.608}, {32.24897, 32.476}, {32.3323, 32.239}, {32.41562, 32.06}, {32.49897, 31.888}, 
  {32.5823, 31.732}, {32.66562, 31.557}, {32.74895, 31.454}, {32.8323, 31.209}, {32.91563, 31.144}, {32.99895, 30.881}, {33.0823, 30.841}, {33.16563, 30.712}, {33.24895, 30.506}, {33.33228, 30.465}, 
  {33.41563, 30.333}, {33.49897, 30.158}, {33.58228, 30.121}, {33.66563, 30.034}, {33.74897, 29.631}, {33.83228, 29.451}, {33.91562, 29.41}, {33.99897, 29.403}, {34.0823, 29.41}, {34.16562, 29.406}, 
  {34.24897, 29.336}, {34.3323, 29.181}, {34.41562, 29.07}, {34.49895, 29.047}, {34.5823, 29.024}, {34.66562, 28.892}, {34.74895, 28.761}, {34.8323, 28.717}, {34.91563, 28.699}, {34.99895, 28.699}, 
  {35.08228, 28.608}, {35.16563, 28.437}, {35.24895, 28.374}, {35.33228, 28.352}, {35.41563, 28.352}, {35.49897, 28.308}, {35.58228, 28.218}, {35.66562, 28.086}, {35.74897, 28.023}, {35.83228, 28.026}, 
  {35.91562, 28.002}, {35.99897, 28.002}, {36.0823, 27.98}, {36.16562, 27.855}, {36.24895, 27.764}, {36.3323, 27.695}, {36.41562, 27.658}, {36.49895, 27.68}, {36.5823, 27.654}, {36.66563, 27.636}, 
  {36.74895, 27.549}, {36.83228, 27.489}, {36.91563, 27.373}, {36.99895, 27.326}, {37.08228, 27.326}, {37.16563, 27.308}, {37.24897, 27.308}, {37.33228, 27.304}, {37.41562, 27.242}, {37.49897, 27.176}, 
  {37.58228, 27.135}, {37.66562, 27.07}, {37.74897, 26.982}, {37.8323, 26.985}, {37.91562, 26.982}, {37.99895, 26.959}, {38.0823, 26.959}, {38.16562, 26.895}, {38.24895, 26.873}, {38.3323, 26.757}, 
  {38.41563, 26.715}, {38.49895, 26.671}, {38.58228, 26.648}, {38.66563, 26.626}, {38.74897, 26.63}, {38.8323, 26.626}, {38.91565, 26.603}, {38.99898, 26.603}, {39.0823, 26.581}, {39.16563, 26.581}, 
  {39.24898, 26.562}, {39.3323, 26.536}, {39.41563, 26.428}, {39.49898, 26.36}, {39.58232, 26.293}, {39.66563, 26.293}, {39.74897, 26.267}, {39.83232, 26.271}, {39.91563, 26.248}, {39.99897, 26.248}}
*)

PR2 = NonlinearModelFit[coolingpart2, a*Exp[-t/taus] + c, {a, c, taus}, t]
```

> During evaluation of In[81]:=
>   NonlinearModelFit::cvmit

```
PR2["ParameterTable"]

PR2[2.52]
(*959379.3488013976*)
```

Third cooling section:

```
coolingpart3 = data3[[30050 ;; 35000 ;; 60]]

(*
{{50.08237, 45.135}, {50.18237, 43.843}, {50.28238, 42.505}, {50.38238, 41.257}, {50.48237, 40.183}, {50.58238, 39.332}, {50.68238, 38.497}, {50.78237, 37.753}, {50.88238, 37.143}, {50.98238, 36.526}, 
  {51.08237, 35.938}, {51.18238, 35.456}, {51.28237, 35.106}, {51.38237, 34.646}, {51.48238, 34.184}, {51.58237, 33.784}, {51.68237, 33.495}, {51.78238, 33.181}, {51.88238, 32.958}, {51.98238, 32.629}, 
  {52.0824, 32.301}, {52.18238, 32.188}, {52.28238, 31.925}, {52.3824, 31.644}, {52.48238, 31.578}, {52.58238, 31.25}, {52.6824, 31.184}, {52.78238, 30.899}, {52.88238, 30.856}, {52.9824, 30.546}, 
  {53.08238, 30.483}, {53.1824, 30.286}, {53.2824, 30.177}, {53.38238, 30.111}, {53.4824, 29.62}, {53.58245, 29.441}, {53.68243, 29.441}, {53.78245, 29.441}, {53.88245, 29.441}, {53.98243, 29.306}, 
  {54.08245, 29.171}, {54.18245, 29.101}, {54.28243, 29.014}, {54.38245, 28.86}, {54.48243, 28.751}, {54.58243, 28.751}, {54.68245, 28.707}, {54.78243, 28.532}, {54.88245, 28.422}, {54.98247, 28.401}, 
  {55.08245, 28.379}, {55.18245, 28.291}, {55.28247, 28.182}, {55.38245, 28.05}, {55.48245, 28.05}, {55.58247, 28.028}, {55.68245, 28.006}, {55.78245, 27.963}, {55.88247, 27.788}, {55.98245, 27.7}, 
  {56.08245, 27.7}, {56.18247, 27.678}, {56.28245, 27.659}, {56.38245, 27.593}, {56.48247, 27.462}, {56.58245, 27.396}, {56.68247, 27.352}, {56.78247, 27.352}, {56.88245, 27.352}, {56.98247, 27.331}, 
  {57.08247, 27.287}, {57.18245, 27.203}, {57.28247, 27.09}, {57.38248, 27.024}, {57.48247, 27.002}, {57.58248, 27.006}, {57.68248, 26.98}, {57.78247, 26.961}, {57.88248, 26.867}, {57.98248, 26.759}, 
  {58.08248, 26.688}, {58.1825, 26.67}, {58.28248, 26.643}}
*)
```

For Blackbody radiation:

```
(*specific heat capacity of (water:J/g - K)*)
cw = 4.18; 

(*mass of water in gm*)
mw = 3;

(*linear cooling constant*)
A = 1; 

(*radiative cooling constant*)
B = 1; 

(*ambient temperature in degrees C*)
Ta = 20; 

(*power absorbed in W*)
P = 1000/10^3; 


Module[{temperature}, FinalTemperature[time_, P_, Ta_, A_, B_, mw_, cw_] := (sol1 = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] == P/(mw*cw) - A*(y[x] - Ta) - B*((y[x] + 273)^4 - (Ta + 273)^4), y[0] == Ta}, y, {x, 0, time}]; 
    temperature = Evaluate[y[time] /. sol1][[1]]; temperature)]

N[FinalTemperature[200, P, Ta, A, B, mw, cw]]

(*20.0000000007926*)

sol2 = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] == P/(mw*cw) - A*(y[x] - Ta) - B*((y[x] + 273)^4 - (Ta + 273)^4), y[0] == Ta}, y, {x, 0, 500}]

(*{{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 500.}}, "<>"]}}*)

Evaluate[y[500] /. sol2][[1]]
(*20.00000000079259*)
```

[image: code with nonlinear fit equation]

I added the code I have used to find time constant. On x-axis its time and y-axis temperature.It has huge data points.I want to shift the time axis to 0 as it is affecting the time constant's value. Also before doing nonlinear fit to this graph I want to eliminate black body radiation error from it. That is given by Equation Q=a*[T^4-Tamb^4] where a is boltzman constant, T is the temperature given in image and Tamb is 25.

My queries are "How to I shift time to zero so that my time constant value come out as a realistic number"

Secondly can I plot and subtract black body radiation values from original data points.

Hope it is making some sense now.

Comment: @MarcoB My apologies for being naive. Is there anyway I can upload my code file here?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your question (click the "edit" link at the bottom of the question on the left) then paste your RELEVANT code. Edit the code so only the relevant portion with which you have an issue is included, but do include any definitions of symbols you use, and data. See also [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951), and here is also a quick cheatsheet on formatting: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Minahil, please include code and data AS TEXT, so we can copy/paste the code and run it ourselves. See the "How to copy code..." link I included in my previous comment.

Comment: @MarcoB it has 30,000+ data points. I have left relevent cooling part input from which I have to find time constant. It is changing drastically from one cooling cycle to the second cooling cycle. That is not a realistic thing and I cannot figure out the bug in the black body radiation equation.